# I can't use static private IP address of docker container outside EC2 instance on same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker-compose, netflix-eureka, static-ip-address

I've implemented a user-microservice to an ec2 server other than a eureka registry server that also has a cms-microservice when I go to the Eureka dashboard to see all of these services up and running with their ports. But when implicitly cms-microservice call user-service, I got no available microservice with this name, or sometimes a connection time-out.
In docker-compose I'm using a static ip-address of every docker container, with a specific subnet, and gateway and bridging network. And outside the eureka server, I used a private IP address of Ec2 instance in serviceUrl.defaultZone and all services are shown there but no response returned. 
So my question is what do I need to reach the private IP of the docker container inside a private IP of Ec2 instance? Do I need natting if yes, can anyone tell me the way to do it?

Note: my instance is using a centOs.

Comment: Have you set your security groups to allow traffic in your VPC?

Comment: Do you mean to allow access from instance to another by using that security group in the other one? if so, yes I did with no luck and I didn't get any. and if you're asking if opened the ports I also did and eureka registry see others